# How do I use this ArcMenu library in my project when it doesn't have the gradle compile in the usage?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like to use this ArcMenu view in my project:

> https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu

Normally, I copy and paste the `compile 'com.example.library'` into my `build.gradle` file. This library doesn't have something like this under the usage.

The usage is confusing to me:

> $ android update project --library ../relative/path/to/the/library
>   --path .

How am I supposed to include and use this library in this situation? Do I have to figure out the compile 'com.example.library' myself?

Sorry for my ignorance. I don't know much about gradle and I'm new to working with it. I appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Version** : Simply import the `library` folder as a module in your project and add as a dependency via the project structure option.

**Long Version** :

[image]

- Put this under your `build.gradle` for the app

  ```
   dependencies {
     compile project(':library')
     ...
   }
  ```

  or Goto

  > Project Structure > app > Dependency Tab> Click on `+` to add `module` dependency > choose `library`

**UPDATE**

As per your comment `build.gradle` should be looking like this
[image]

Which is that the `compileSdkVersion` is set to 4 where as it should be set to whatever you have in your app, in my case its `23` . Also update the `buildToolsVersion`.

Update the `build.gradle` of the `library` module as below

[image]

[Working demonstration app on github.](https://github.com/nisrulz/android-examples/tree/master/UsingArcMenu)

Comment: I've imported the library... now I get this message. Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-4' in: C:\Users\ect\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: My build.gradle already had the compileSdkVersion 23 and buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' Thank you for the quick reply. Any ideas?

Comment: I am pretty sure your "app" build.gradle has 23 and 23.0.2 as respective entries. My answer points to one under the "library" module. Switch to Project View > goto library module> open it up > you will see build.gradle. Now update as specified.

Comment: Just FYI I basically built the whole project from scratch. If you want I can upload it on github.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me like you need to download the project and add it as a library module to your application.

for more, read [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#SettingUpLibraryModule)

Answer (score 0):

You have to download library and import as a module into your android studio project.

1) Right click on your project->select open module setting

2) Project Structure dialog will open

3) Select your app from the left side of project structure dialog.

4) Go on dependency tab and click '+' at right side of dialog.

5) Select Module Dependency and import your downloaded library project.